# What Magic: The Gathering novel/character involves removing someone's memories through a hole in their skull?

Tags: story-identification, character-identification, mind-control, magic-the-gathering

There's a plotline in a Magic: The Gathering novel I'm having trouble remembering, and I'd like to find what book it's in. Basically, there's a Phyrexian (possibly was a human before?) who loves knowledge, and part of their Phyrexian augmentations is a hole in their skull. Late in the story, they're either dying or just failing and their leader comes up to them, and rather than helping their leader uses that hole to drain all their knowledge out.

I believe this happens on Rath, and would have been around the Nemesis block. It's possible this happens in Nemesis itself, but I can't find reference to this scene online and don't own the book, so I can't check.

What character is this that has the hole in their head, and what book was this scene in?